# Unsolved CSS3 transform-rotation, only in Chrome. Rotate and hiding div :(?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, css

Hello I have a problem witz hiding div. 
Here is an example (try it only in Chrome) http://jsfiddle.net/Fy7qW/5/

Look what happen when angle is -40 and -50.
Is there any way to get good rendering while rotating?

Or is there any way to display divs like this: [image with example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cV7IA.png)

Comment: I'm totally not up to date with what's going on in bleeding edge CSS and general direction etc. but if your intention is to expand your example into a more complete framework I think you're using the wrong tools. WebGL is much more suited to do that. Although if you're just doing a toy example then forget everything I just wrote.

Comment: consider using canvas for what you might be trying to do

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you will need to dynamically adjust z-indexes or restructure the DOM to alter the bottom-up display order.

so basically if `$('#kat').val()` is ever one of those buggy angles, apply a different display structure.